# JPA/Hibernate why removal of all children doesn't issue delete by parent id

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

There is a good [article](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-batch-delete-statements-with-hibernate/) with some deletion tricks explained, but there is something I still can't grasp.

Let's take entity from that article.

```
public class Post {
  @OneToMany(
    mappedBy = "post",
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
    orphanRemoval = true
  )
  private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();    
}
```

And let's say I want to remove ALL comments at once. There are multiple approaches:

1. `post.comments.clear()` this would issue N delete statements like: `delete from comment where comment_id=n`
2. iterator based approach with `comment.post = null, iterator.remove()` Same story with `delete from comment where comment_id=n`
3. `entityManager.remove(post)` Same story.

I can't understand why in all those cases I don't see a query like
`delete from comment where parent=X`
Is there any specific reason for that?

Am I right that the best solution to achieve it is to execute jpql/hql query directly: `delete from comment where parent=X`. Are there any downsides of that approach? (i.e. hibernate caches are not updated or something)